# Javascript switch statement not working properly cant find solution

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a new project but have some issues with this bit of javascript. I cant figure out what is wrong and hope you can help me.

What I want my peice of code to do is count var i to 4, when it hits 4 set i to 0 and start again. The issue is that the switch statement only executes case 0 eventhough i is set to 1. I tried switching everything to strings but doesnt seem to help.

```js
function bckLoad() {
  var i = 0;

  switch (i) {
    case 0:
      i = 1;
      var leftPos = $('#index-header').scrollLeft();
      $("#index-header").animate({
        scrollLeft: leftPos + 1940
      }, 800);
      window.alert("Test");
      break;
    case 1:
      i = 2;
      var leftPos = $('#index-header').scrollLeft();
      $("#index-header").animate({
        scrollLeft: leftPos + 1940
      }, 800);
      window.alert("test1");
      break;
    case 2:
      i = 3;
      var leftPos = $('#index-header').scrollLeft();
      $("#index-header").animate({
        scrollLeft: leftPos + 1940
      }, 800);
      window.alert("test2");
      break;
    case 3:
      i = 4;
      var leftPos = $('#index-header').scrollLeft();
      $("#index-header").animate({
        scrollLeft: leftPos + 1940
      }, 800);
      window.alert("test3");
      break;
    case 4:
      i = 0;
      var leftPos = $('#index-header').scrollLeft();
      $("#index-header").animate({
        scrollLeft: leftPos - 7760
      }, 800);
      window.alert("test4");
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}
var intervalID = window.setInterval(bckLoad, 6000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="index-header">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <h1>Home</h1>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <h1>Blog</h1>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <h1>About</h1>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <h1>Contact</h1>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `break;` will stop evaluating the other cases. In any case, `switch` is probably not the best approach for what you're trying to do, a loop will be more appropriate.

Comment: Is this your actual logic, as it seems completely redundant?

Comment: Everytime you call the function you are telling to execute the switch-case 0 with your statement var i = 0;

Comment: @titus just if the loop gets `yield`ed or `await`ed.

Comment: @JonasWilms Yes, I took a better look and I think I was wrong, I thought the OP wanted to run through all the cases every time the `bckLoad` function is called.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Move

```
 var i = 0;
```

outside of the function. Otherwise it will be reset every time.

How I would do that:

```
  const leftBy = [1940, 1940, 1940, -7760];
  let i = 0;

  function animate() {
    const leftPos = $('#index-header').scrollLeft();
    $("#index-header").animate({scrollLeft: leftPos + leftBy[i]}, 800);                       
    window.alert(`Test${i}`);
    i = (i + 1) % 5;
  }

  setInterval(animate, 6000);
```

Comment: Nice! Perhaps wrap it in `function bckLoad() { }` and return the interval handle so it matches the OP's?

Comment: @t.j. I leave that to the other great answers ;)

Comment: @SrRazer__ glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

You're setting `i` to `0` every time you call the function, so it doesn't remember the value between different calls. You need to move the variable outside the function.

There's also no need for the `switch()` statement, since you do the same thing in each case except for the new value of `i`. But that value is just adding `1` and wrapping around.

```
var i = 0;

function bckLoad() {
    i = (i + 1) % 5;
    var leftPos = $('#index-header').scrollLeft();
    $("#index-header").animate({
        scrollLeft: leftPos + (i > 0 ? 1940 : -7760)
    }, 800);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look closely to the first line after your function declaration:

```
            var i = 0;
```

That line is running every time that you call `window.setInterval(bckLoad, 6000);`, as `bckLoad` function is being called is asigning the value of i to 0 each time that it runs. You have to get the variable devlaration out of the function, such as this:

```
var i = 0;
function bckLoad(){

        switch(i){
            case 0:
                i = 1;
                var leftPos = $('#index-header').scrollLeft();
                $("#index-header").animate({scrollLeft: leftPos + 1940}, 800);                       
                window.alert("Test");
                break;
            case 1:
                i = 2;
                var leftPos = $('#index-header').scrollLeft();
                $("#index-header").animate({scrollLeft: leftPos + 1940}, 800);                     
                window.alert("test1");
                break;
            case 2:
                i = 3;
                var leftPos = $('#index-header').scrollLeft();
                $("#index-header").animate({scrollLeft: leftPos + 1940}, 800);                        
                window.alert("test2");
                break;
            case 3:
                i = 4;  
                var leftPos = $('#index-header').scrollLeft();
                $("#index-header").animate({scrollLeft: leftPos + 1940}, 800);                       
                window.alert("test3");
                break;
            case 4:
                i = 0;
                var leftPos = $('#index-header').scrollLeft();
                $("#index-header").animate({scrollLeft: leftPos - 7760}, 800);
                window.alert("test4");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }        
    }
    var intervalID = window.setInterval(bckLoad, 6000);
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
  var i = 0; // moved outside , it's logical :)

  function bckLoad() {
```

// taking care of redundant code

```
  switch (i) {
    case 0:
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
      i = (i+1)%5;// resetting to 0 once it reaches to 4
      var leftPos = $('#index-header').scrollLeft();

      $("#index-header").animate({
        scrollLeft: leftPos + (i==0?-7760:1940)
      }, 800);

      window.alert("test"+(i==0?"":i));

      break;
      default :
      break;
  }
}

var intervalID = window.setInterval(bckLoad, 6000);
```